# Is there a way to get answers from a google form and use those values to make a user in google admin?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

Initially I was taking in values from a form and getting the responses to a google sheet and then using the lastRow function I was pulling data of the user and creating the user in Google Admin but that still requires me to run the script every time the form is filled.
Is it possible to directly take values from the form and then use those values to create this user? Because then I could just use onFormSubmit() and automatically trigger the method.

Please help me out, thanks!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#add_user  reference is here. Take a look.

Answer (score 1):

something like this. It should work

```
   function onFormSubmit(e) {
        const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
        const items = form.getItems();
        const formResponses = e.response;
    
        const data = {};
        const header_youneed = ['FirstName', 'LastName']
    
        for (i in items) {
            let response = formResponses.getResponseForItem(items[i]).getResponse();
            if (header_youneed.indexOf(items[i].getTitle()) > -1) {
                data[items[i].getTitle()] = response;
            }
        }
    
        //add user
        addUser(data);
    
    }
    
    
    function addUser(data) {
        let user = {
            // TODO (developer) - Replace primaryEmail value with yours
            primaryEmail: data['FirstName'] + data['LastName'] + '@companydomain.com',
            name: {
                givenName: data['FirstName'],
                familyName: data['LastName']
            },
            // Generate a random password string.
            password: Math.random().toString(36)
        };
        try {
            user = AdminDirectory.Users.insert(user);
            Logger.log('User %s created with ID %s.', user.primaryEmail, user.id);
        } catch (err) {
            // TODO (developer)- Handle exception from the API
            Logger.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
        }
    }
```